# Combine row aggregate data with individual rows

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table looking like below

`base_data`

| session_id | event_type | player_guess | correct_answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | guess | 'python' | NULL |
| 1 | guess | 'javascript' | NULL |
| 1 | guess | 'scala' | NULL |
| 1 | all_answered | NULL | ['python','javascript','hadoop'] |
| 2 | guess | 'triangle' | NULL |
| 2 | guess | 'square' | NULL |
| 2 | all_answered | NULL | ['triangle','square'] |

I am trying to get a new column called as `was_guess_correct` defined as follow :

```
For each session_id, match the player_guess values with data in correct_answer. Correct answer for session_id is available when event_type = 'all_answered'
```

The result would look like -

| session_id | event_type | player_guess | correct_answer | was_guess_correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | guess | 'python' | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | guess | 'javascript' | NULL | 1 |
| 1 | guess | 'scala' | NULL | 0 |
| 1 | all_answered | NULL | ['python','javascript','hadoop'] | 1 |
| 2 | guess | 'triangle' | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | guess | 'square' | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | all_answered | NULL | ['triangle','square'] | 1 |

The values in row all_answered are unique as well as sorted ( The order can be used or just checking using `IN` clause might also work )

For row with event_type `all_answered`, the column `was_guess_correct` does not matter. It can be 1 or 0 - whatever helps makes the query easier.

How would I be able to compute the above column in SQL/ Presto ?

I am trying to see - How to compute using JOIN/Unnest and also inline (without JOIN) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the correct answers on each row.  Then how you manage the result depends on the type of the column.  If it is a string, you can just use `like`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when event_type = 'all_answered' or
                  max(correct_answer) over (partition by session_id) like  '%''' || player_guess || '''%'
             then 1 else 0 
        end) as was_guess_correct
from t;
```

Note that `correct_answer` is `NULL` in the "guess" rows, so `max()` works (assuming there is one correct answer row per session).